# How to use the HTTP API with a Proxy?

Tags: wp-remote-request, proxy, http-api

If I want to route a HTTP request through a local (alias: on the current server) Proxy, how would I go around this?

The allowed Proxy settings for the `wp-config.php` are the following:

```
# HTTP Proxies
# Used for e.g. in Intranets
# Fixes Feeds as well
# Defines the proxy adresse.
define( 'WP_PROXY_HOST',          '127.0.84.1' );
# Defines the proxy port.
define( 'WP_PROXY_PORT',          '8080' );
# Defines the proxy username.
define( 'WP_PROXY_USERNAME',      'my_user_name' );
# Defines the proxy password.
define( 'WP_PROXY_PASSWORD',      'my_password' );
# Allows you to define some adresses which 
# shouldn't be passed through a proxy.
define( 'WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS',  'localhost, www.example.com' );
```

<sup>*This question is [a follow up on this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22858/how-can-i-setup-wordpress-behind-a-reverse-proxy/71523#comment101932_71523).*</sup>

Comment: I don't understand the question, exactly. You seem to have the answer right there. Those are the proxy settings for the HTTP API. If you have to go through a proxy to make external requests, then yep, that's how you do it.

Comment: Read the initial question: Yes, these have nothing to do with reverse proxies. These are for making requests from WP to the outside world, through a proxy server.

Comment: @Otto Yes, the answer is clear and yes it came out of the other question. Glad you got that point. WPSE is a reference system and lives from explanations and details not provided elsewhere or provided with more detail here... hence the question.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why did you ask the question if you already knew the answer? Edit: You know what, nevermind, don't bother to explain. I'll just downvote and vote to delete it, because this makes no sense and shouldn't be here.

Comment: @Otto As I stumbled upon your comment again: See [this screenshot please](http://i.imgur.com/fTJM5FT.png).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proxy settings work just like a regular HTTP requests but in this case obviously routed through a proxy. In terms of WordPress the API's transport layers all support proxy connections(fsockopen, fopen, cURL, ).

The things about proxy configurations are they come in several flavors and each setup is different so it makes answering this difficult, it doesn't really matter if your proxy is on your localhost or remote, the `wp-config.php` settings will work regardless. Typically you want to use these settings if your on an intranet/firewall that has specific requirements.

It is worth noting you can just set your localhost/webserver to use a proxy/chaining by default for HTTP requests and in that case it is *not* necessary to set any options with `wp-config.php` since this is configured at the server level . If you disable your proxy you typically see a response code of `error 130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED`, but these setups are outside the scope of WordPress.

Some tools that can help you setup and debug proxy connections:

- Fiddler (Windows only). http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
- Charles  http://www.charlesproxy.com/
- Squid  http://www.squid-cache.org/

To dig into the WordPress HTTP API I recommend the following snippet using the `http_api_debug` action (altered to `var_dump` found via viper007bond's site):

```
add_action( 'http_api_debug', 'viper_http_api_debug', 10, 5 );

function viper_http_api_debug( $response, $type, $class, $args, $url ) {
    // You can change this from error_log() to var_dump() but it can break AJAX requests
    var_dump( 'Request URL: ' . var_export( $url, true ) );
    var_dump( 'Request Args: ' . var_export( $args, true ) );
    var_dump( 'Request Response : ' . var_export( $response, true ) );
}
```

The *Request Response* is the interesting part, sometimes you can tell with a quick glance if your request is going through proxy..

For example using the default HTTP API to make the following request.

```
$api_url = 'http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.0/';
$response = wp_remote_get($api_url);
$header = wp_remote_retrieve_headers( $response );

var_dump($header);
```

[image]

Now the same exact request but using a remote proxy enabled via wp-config.php

```
//I grabbed these off of Google search they will not work for long.
define( 'WP_PROXY_HOST', '210.22.115.162' );
define( 'WP_PROXY_PORT', '3128' );
```

[image]

As you can see the proxy the output is different, most importantly the proxy is adding the `via` tag, in this case a squid proxy. Proxies are *supposed* to do this and **not** alter the server response-header , but not everyone follows the rules so be careful;).

The constant `define( 'WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS',  'localhost, www.example.com' )` is useful for allowing access to hosts that you might not want to go through a proxy (WordPress updates for example). The comments in the `class-http.php` are misleading because by default `localhost` and `get_option('siteurl);` are already included but can be altered via the `pre_http_send_through_proxy` filter.

Some additional options that work with the proxy settings are:
`WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL` `WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS`